# Fragments in 2.3 crashing app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to implement fragments in a 2.2/2.3 android project using the android.support v4 jar but it keeps crashing and giving me this error:

```
06-07 14:23:43.774: E/AndroidRuntime(3085): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{mike.android.ie/mike.android.ie.ActivityView}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mike.android.ie.ActivityView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/mike.android.ie-1.apk]
```

I had other fragments in the code but have commented it out to just try get one fragment working,  I would apreciate it if you could help me.

the classes I am using are:

**ActivityView.java**

```
package mike.android.ie;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class ActivityView extends FragmentActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 }
}
```

and the **main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="mike.android.ie.ImageViewFragment" android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/image_fragment" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

then I have a **ImageViewFragment.java**:

```
package mike.android.ie;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageViewFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ImageView image = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagefragment, container, false);

    return image;

}

}
```

and the **imagefragment.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/myimage01" />
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityView"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ImageViewFragment" android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation" />
    <activity android:name=".TickerFragment" android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation" />
    <activity android:name=".WebViewFragment" android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation" />
    <activity android:name=".VideoViewFragment" android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation" />
</application>
```

Comment: Do you have ActivityView declared in your manifest properly?

Comment: I think I have, I added the manifest above.

Comment: I had to delete the support v4 .jar and make a folder called libs then copied the support jar into that folder, I also had to change my fragment in the main xml from android:name="mike.android.ie" to class="mike.android.ie"

Answer (score 0):

The error: `mike.android.ie/mike.android.ie.ActivityView` does NOT look like the standard fragments compa lib. Is there any other lib you included wich could cause this bug?

Comment: `mike.android.ie` is my package name and the only lib I added was the support.v4 jar

Answer (score 0):

In your main.xml:

```
<fragment class="mike.android.ie.ImageViewFragment" 
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/image_fragment" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
/>
```

Comment: I've just noticed - have you specified package in your manifest file? You seem to have ommited <manifest> element